# Copy PDF content inside an iframe to an embed element

Tags: javascript, pdf, iframe, embed

First, don't know if this is possible but if it is it would be awesome.

I need to copy the iframe content ( is displaying a pdf created on the fly currently, i mean i put in the src attribute of the iframe an url and this url returns me a pdf file something like http://webservice.pdf.com/getpdf/product/1 ) to an embed element.

Something like

```
<iframe src="http://webservice.pdf.com/getpdf/product/1" type="application/pdf" > // this is the iframe that have the pdf file generated on the fly
```

copy to:

```
<embed src="product1.pdf" type="application/pdf">
```

I assume it can be done converting the iframe content to encode base 64 or something like that. The problem is i'm using Internet Explorer 11 and this browser kills is killing.

Ideas or another alternative to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't want to set the embed src directly?

Comment: the problem to set the src in the embed is that the service will try to generate once again the pdf file and this service generates this pdf once :\

Comment: What about trying to GET the file using javascript and loading it to both elements?

Comment: you mean storage first and then show the pdf file?